# camera: Undefined class 'XFile'

Tags: flutter, camera

I decided to work again on a project I started 4 months ago, and for that I'm starting to update my packages.

Since 0.6.0, "camera" now sends the image as an XFile class. Except that while trying to update my code, I get this error :

```
Undefined class 'XFile'.
```

I don't know where this class comes from. How can I avoid these problems? Do I have to install another package?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay my bad, I mistyped a wrong version of another package, so it was not updated actually.

Comment: So how your solve that problem.please explain.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to your project root directory and run the following command I think it should help
`flutter pub add image_picker`